# PHP framework AMPHP/THREAD no longer in use?

Tags: multithreading, amphp

Was amphp/thread discontinued? amphp/amp is working perfectly but when I run ANY of the example coding from amphp/thread git, I get all kinds of errors. Not one example is working. I noticed last update was in 2014.

Is there any way for me to get amphp/thread working? Was it replaced? With what replacement?

I have php 7.0 installed on mac, built with thread safety. EV, EVENT, UV are all enabled.

My .jason file looks like this  "amphp/amp": "v0.17.0", "amphp/thread": "v0.8.1"

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question in a discussion here:
https://github.com/amphp/thread/issues/14

amphp/thread is no longer being supported but there is hope that it will be picked up again in the future to work with amphp/amp v2. No concrete timeline on when this will happen was given.

Also, amphp/parallel is considered to be the replacement for amphp/thread.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. It won't be maintained any longer, use `amphp/parallel` instead.